# detecting connected interface using c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, routes

I want to detect which interface is now connected; and I have three 3g-modem connections and two lan connections to the server(my device didn't support wlan). I mean the type of connection is not important but the interface name and specifics is what important for me. I want to detect connected interface in my program that I wrote in c++. please tell me how to detect connected interface in c++?(root permission is not a problem.)

Comment: So... apart from the philosophy of wanting things, is there a question?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes; HOW TO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NetworkManager, you can use it's [API](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/). You can either use the D-Bus API, the GLib wrapping, [C++ Bindings for D-Bus](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/dbus-cplusplus/index.php?title=Main_Page).

If you are using Qt, you can directly use [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/topics-network-connectivity.html).

Of course, you can also go very low-level and use [`ioctl(7)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/7/ioctl). See [lsif](https://github.com/ajrisi/lsif/blob/master/lsif.c) by [Adam Risi](http://www.adamrisi.com/?p=132) for an example.

Comment: thanks for your answer but your ioctl link is broken (although it's very easy to find ioctl manual on internet).

Comment: Thanks, fixed (. and / are really close together on my keyboard...)

Answer (score 9):

Use `ioctl` `SIOCGIFFLAGS` to check is the interface UP and RUNNING:

```
struct ifreq ifr;

memset( &ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr) );
strcpy( ifr.ifr_name, ifrname );

if( ioctl( dummy_fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr ) != -1 )
{
    up_and_running = (ifr.ifr_flags & ( IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING )) == ( IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING );
}
else
{
    // error
}
```

Input variable is `ifrname`. It should be the interface name "eth0", eth1", "ppp0" ....

Because `ioctl()` needs a file descriptor as parameter, you can use for example some temporary UDP socket for that:

```
dummy_fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
```

Remember to close the socket, when not used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use netlink route sockets. See [libnetlink](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/libnetlink/) library, or man 7 netlink and man 7 rtnetlink.